# is zakaat applicable on childrens marriage gifts

Tags: zakat

Is Zakat applicable on the money,gold and other items kept by parents as marriage gift for their children.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model i.e. what is on- and what is off-topic here I suggest you to take the [Tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't mention all the kind of gifts you refer to. You should know that any kind of wealth about which we know that it is a duty to pay zakat from if it reaches the nisaab (the amount which is the lower limit to obligate zakat) and a full lunar year (hawl) has past with it in our possession is a due to zakat, be it money, gold, silver, cows, sheep etc.. It doesn't matter if it was considered as a later gift, as even later it would be a due for zakat for your children if the conditions of zakat are fulfilled (nisaab, hawl).